# Joining table to feature class based on two or more fields using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, relates

I have a table and I would like to join it to a polygon feature class but based on two columns. As in if the polygon has the same values in in column A and column B it will join. If the table has the same values in column A and not in column B then it will not join.

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

Comment: Don't forget to build an index on the join columns in the target FC.

Answer (score 3):

If your datasets exist all in the same Geodatabase then you could use the [Make Query Table tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm). This will allow you to join data using multiple fields. Note this is a temporary in-memory layer and you would need to save it to make it permanent.

Answer (score 2):

You could Field Calculate a new field in the polygon table of both A and B then join on this.